# How to use batch file to give a folder permission to the Everyone group

Tags: batch-file, permissions, file-permissions, icacls

Im trying to add the group `Everyone` and give it `modify` permissions on a folder. Im using a batch file to try this. so for I have `icacls "C:\Program Files (x86)\Program File" /grant:r Everyone:M`
But when I go and look at the permissions on the folder nothing has been changed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No need to put `:r` after `/grant`. Check the examples by typing `icacls /?`

Do like this:

```
icacls "C:\Program Files (x86)\Program File" /grant Everyone:M
```

Comment: will this add the permission on the folder? or only on files?

Comment: It'll provide the permission on `Program File` folder.

Comment: So if the Everyone isn't previously on the folder permissions will it add it?

Comment: Yes, It'll grant `MODIFY` permission to group`Everyone`.