# Windows command line change folder permission

Tags: windows, command-line, permissions

The scenario is as follows:

- A program that's executed with admin rights creates a folder, "C:\my folder".
- In cmd, I want to grant full control of this folder to everyone.

How can I do it? I tried

```
cacls "C:\my folder" /E /P "*S-1-1-0":F
```

and didn't work. I also tried

```
cacls "C:\my folder" /E /P "Everyone":F
```

and didn't work. Yet,

```
cacls "C:\my folder" /E /P "Todos":F
```

did work -- where "Todos" stands for "Everyone" in a Spanish installation of Windows. How can I accomplish this no matter what language Windows was installed with?

NOTE: I know cacls is supposed to be deprecated in favour of icacls. I don't mind. Please, don't waste your time pointing it out, unless there is a way to achieve this in icacls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my own dispare, I finally managed to figure it out:
`icacls "C:\my folder" /GRANT *S-1-1-0:F`
This is funny: I figured it out by means of technet.microsoft.com, YET, THEIR OWN DOCUMENTATION IS WRONG!!!
IN https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/cc753525(v=ws.10).aspx they state you should use 
`Icacls test2 GRANT *S-1-1-0:(d,wdac)` 
when you should actually use 
`Icacls test2 /GRANT *S-1-1-0:(d,wdac)`

Comment: The example is correct in the original English version of the article. The automatic translation to Spanish breaks it.

Comment: Wrong documentation, as I stated before.

Comment: In Spanish you're looking at an *automatically* translated document from the *correct* English version, and somehow the translation software messes up the example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
icacls "C:\my folder" /grant Everyone:M
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23526976/8392301).

Comment: Not working.  I think (yet not entirely sure) anyhing related with "Everyone" won't just work on a spanish windows